# Rails: What is 'my' in ActiveRecord where class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

It's very strange. I don't see any documentation for the usage of **'my'** in where class. Can anyone please explain the below.

```
1.9.3-p547 :006 >  reser = Date.today
 => Thu, 18 Dec 2014
1.9.3-p547 :011 > Reservation.where { start_date >= reser }.count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."start_date" >= '2014-12-18'
 => 63
1.9.3-p547 :012 > Reservation.where { start_date >= my { reser } }.count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."start_date" >= '2014-12-18'
 => 63
```

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem that extends AR. See the [Query DSL](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#the-squeel-query-dsl).

Comment: Thanks. I can see this in the documentation (Wrap the method or instance variable inside the block with my{}). But why the word 'my' in  where class?

Comment: @Mr.Black It's just the name of the method defined in the DSL. See [#my](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/blob/master/lib/squeel/dsl.rb#L62). As for its usage, when you're inside the curly brackets, the evaluation context is changed to the DSL (so you can call its methods) but that also means you cannot refer directly to the methods/instance variables defined in the object itself (your model for example). The `my` method is there to  solve the problem by evaluating the block inside the original object.